# How does Linux determine the default MAC address of a bridge device?

Tags: linux, bridge

How does Linux determine the default MAC address of a bridge device? I know it is the same as "bridge id" from `brctl show`, but how is it calculated? Is the MAC address supposed to change automatically when a network interface is added to the bridge?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Behavior might possibly have changed in the past depending on kernel version, but currently (here: kernel 5.17.x) it appears that:

- if the bridge has not be manually given a MAC address then

  - it initially gets an autogenerated random MAC address with private bit set (ie: 2nd digit in MAC address' first byte is always 2,6,a or e).
  - until the first time an interface is set as bridge port, when administratively UP it gets a LOWER_UP flag and its operstate is UNKNOWN, which gives it the benefit of the doubt as if UP (eg with `systl -w net.ipv4.conf.br0.ignore_routes_with_linkdown=1`, route is working and doesn't have the `linkdown` property).
  - once at least one interface has ever been enslaved as bridge port:

    - each time a bridge port is added or removed the bridge interface dynamically inherits the lowest MAC address among all its bridge ports' MAC addresses.
    - should it then lose all of its interfaces, its MAC address becomes 00:00:00:00:00:00, until a port is added back
    - its operstate is UP if it's administratively UP and at least one of its bridge ports has operstate UP (usually: administratively UP and has carrier, ie: doesn't have the NO-CARRIER property)
    - if administratively UP but all of its ports have operstate DOWN (usually: administratively DOWN or have the NO-CARRIER property) then the bridge interface gets the NO-CARRIER property and its operstate is DOWN (and for example with `ignore_routes_with_linkdown=1`, routes will have the `dead`/`linkdown` properties).
- if the bridge's MAC address is set manually (with a different value than from its current auto-generated or inherited address if not set at creation)

  - the bridge's MAC address will not change when bridge ports are added or removed
  - operstate isn't UNKNOWN when administratively set UP when there has never been any bridge port added yet: it's DOWN.
  - and follows the previously described behavior with regard to its operstate and its port's operstates : UP when there's at least a bridge port with operstate UP, DOWN otherwise.

---

I couldn't find any documentation explaining the reason for these different behaviors related to having or not having set a MAC address on the bridge on Linux. There might possibly be an historical relation to how the bridge id is evaluated.

To avoid any surprise, just set the MAC address.

Example for a bridge named `br0`:

```
ip link set dev br0 address 12:34:56:78:9a:bc
```

or at creation:

```
ip link add name br0 address 12:34:56:78:9a:bc up type bridge
```

One can still set it with the MAC address of some pre-existing (physical) interface intended to be enslaved, for example to avoid changing DHCP behavior when requesting an IP address on *br0* without using DUID. It should probably be set before enslaving the interface because setting it after might actually have no effect as written above (setting the bridge interface's MAC address to its same current value has no effect and doesn't switch to the second behavior).

For example to copy `eth0`'s MAC address when creating `br0` to keep DHCP behavior consistent (with `eth0` intended to be enslaved to `br0` and on the side of the DHCP server), with the help of JSON output and the `jq` command:

```
ip link add name br0 address "$(ip -json link show dev eth0 | jq -r .[].address)" up type bridge
```

and only then enslave the interface:

```
ip link set dev eth0 up master br0
```

One can only hope existing network configuration tools can do this correctly.

---

Note: just as `ifconfig` or `route` on Linux, `brctl` is an obsolete command. It still uses the older kernel API. This has been superseded by `ip link` plus `bridge` which use the newer [(rt)](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/rtnetlink.7)[netlink API](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/netlink.7) providing new features (eg: *hairpin*), but arguably may have a less human-readable output.

Example of commands:

```
ip -details link show type bridge
bridge -details link show
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The reason why I was wondering is that I converted my physical machine into a virtual one (using libvirt and qemu), which used completely different (virtual) network adapters and MAC addresses, yet I still saw that the bridge was using the same MAC address as before somehow. My first thought was that MAC address was saved somewhere on the disk and set manually, but it turned out that it wasn't. So even after reading this answer I can still not understand how this was possible.

Comment: If you gave your layout (`ip link show type bridge; ip link show type bridge_slave`, if there's only one bridge then `-brief` option can be added) I guess it could be explained.

Comment: And by the way, technically I did answer your question: I explained how the default MAC address is determined. Your specific problem has not been stated, so I couldn't answer it.

Comment: @jurez meanwhile I know why: you are never in the first case. The value (random but always the same) is **set by systemd**. See my answer in this UL SE Q/A: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/719379/how-can-i-make-linux-generate-different-mac-addresses-for-different-bridge-devic/719391#719391

Comment: So if I understand correctly the bridge MAC address is somehow derived from machine ID? This would explain what happened in my case: when I converted the physical machine to virtual I kept the same machine ID, and that's why my bridge in the virtual machine got the same MAC address as previously in the physical machine, even though the virtual network interface was completely different and had different MAC address than the previously used physical interface.

Comment: I'm using `netctl` and not `systemd-networkd`, so that would mean that the connection has to be through `udev` rules.

Comment: The correct solution is in my answer (the 3 commands to change the machine-id) It's not Debian specific but systemd specific. If your init is systemd (and not say init sys v) then it applies, whatever are your network tools. If you want I update my answer, you must first update your question explaining what was your actual problem (which doesn't appear in your question).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I don't think it's worth opening a separate question, I just wanted to get better understanding of the context in this particular case. Would you happen to know where specifically the calculation of the MAC from machine-id happens?

Comment: Really no. it's done by one of the components of systemd whenever it detects a virtual interface appeared (that's easy, try it with `ip monitor`) even if an entirely different tool (eg: ifupdown's ifup) created it. You'd have to search systemd's sources. By the way now, if your problem is solved, please consider marking my answer ans solution, heh.